# crf and preset parameters works with images?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using the following command to process an image, but there is some problem about the lib I'm using between versions with the message Unrecognized option 'crf'.

My question is: Are the **-crf** and **-preset** parameters valid to process images?

```
ffmpeg -y -i CAP6555676870103416368.jpg -i 1618583957943.png -filter_complex "[0:v]transpose=1[bg];[1:v]scale=720:-2[widgets];[bg][widgets]overlay[outfile]" -b:v 1.0k -f image2 -s 288x512 -crf 0 -preset veryslow -map [outfile] 1618583958573.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

For a single JPEG output, use `-qmin 1 -qmax X` where `X` ranges from 1 to 31. Lower is better.

`-crf` is specific to a few video encoders, like x264, x265, libvpx..etc. Same is true of -preset.

Comment: Could you please link some additional documentation about it?